# about the sum of days of each season

Tags: r

I would like to calculate how many days each season accounts for the duration of the start date and end date. Season categories will be Dec/1-Feb/28(winter), March/1-May/31(spring), June/1-August/31(summer) and Sep/1-Nov/30(Fall).

```
df1 <- data.frame(
   ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2) , 
  Date=as.Date(c("2011/1/1","2011/4/1","2012/3/4","2012/9/8",
                 "2013/1/4","2013/2/1"," 2013/6/1"," 2015/3/1")))  

df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(diff = max(Date) - min(Date))
```

For example, id 1 has 616 days. I would like to know how many days each season has.

From 2011/1/ - 2012/9/8
, id 1 has 616 days, I would like to how many days are winter season, spring, summer, fall, respectively.

Like winter (150 days) spring (150 days) summer (150 days) fall (166 days).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why is it that `From 2011/1/1 - 2013/1/4, id 1 has 616 days`? I count 734 days between 2011/1/1 and 2013/1/4.

Comment: Sorry, From 2011/1/ - 2012/9/8.   I edited.

Comment: Can anyone of you answer this question ??